# How can i call/assign individual variables from the list

Tags: flutter, list, dart, dropdownbutton

From the 'Cel' class, I want to transfer data from the 'cel_lista', but only the 'cel' items [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrjgE.png)

`

here is the 'Cel' class code

```
class Cel {
  late String cel;

  late int wartosc = 1;

  Cel({required this.cel, required this.wartosc});

  static List<Cel> cel_lista() {
    return [
      Cel(cel: 'Schudnąć', wartosc: 500),
      Cel(cel: 'utrzymać wagę', wartosc: 0),
      Cel(cel: 'przytyć', wartosc: 500),
    ];
  }
}
```

here is the DropdownButton code:

```
  @override
  State<Cel> createState() => _CelState();
}

class _CelState extends State<Cel> {
  String dropdownValue = cel_lista.cel.first;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      value: dropdownValue,
      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
      elevation: 16,

      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      underline: Container(
        height: 2,

        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      onChanged: (String? value) {
        // This is called when the user selects an item.
        setState(() {
          dropdownValue = value!;
        });
      },
      items: list.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );

  }
}
```

`

I want to assign the variable 'imie' to text [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jruV9.png)
`

here is the User class code:

```
class User {
   String? imie;
  late int wiek;
  late int waga;
  late int wzrost;

  User(
      {required this.wiek,
      required this.imie,
      required this.waga,
      required this.wzrost});

  static List<User> dane_User() {
    return [User(wiek: 22, imie: 'Monika', waga: 80, wzrost: 190)];
  }
}
```

here is the TEXT item code

```
Text(
  User.dane_User(imie!),
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  style: GoogleFonts.lato(
      textStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20.0,
          height: 1.2,
          color: Colors.white,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
)
```

`

I tried to call the object but unsuccessfully I lack knowledge

Comment: Your requirements are not clear. Pl share relevant code instead of sharing images.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the answer to your first question:** 
I have modified your class Cel, I have converted cel_lista method to a getter.

```
class Cel {
  late String cel;

  late int wartosc = 1;

  Cel({required this.cel, required this.wartosc});

   // converted method to a getter
  static List<Cel> get cel_lista {
    return [
      Cel(cel: 'Schudnąć', wartosc: 500),
      Cel(cel: 'utrzymać wagę', wartosc: 0),
      Cel(cel: 'przytyć', wartosc: 500),
    ];
  }
}
```

So the line that was giving error will be like this:
Before

```
String dropdownValue = cel_lista.cel.first;
```

After:

```
String dropdownValue = cel_lista.first.cel;
```

**Answer to your second question**

Convert your dane_User method to getter

```
class User {
   String? imie;
  late int wiek;
  late int waga;
  late int wzrost;

  User(
      {required this.wiek,
      required this.imie,
      required this.waga,
      required this.wzrost});

  static List<User> get dane_User {
    return [User(wiek: 22, imie: 'Monika', waga: 80, wzrost: 190)];
  }
}
```

Then your Text widget will be:

Before:

```
Text(
  User.dane_User(imie!),
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  style: GoogleFonts.lato(
      textStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20.0,
          height: 1.2,
          color: Colors.white,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
)
```

After:

```
Text(
  User.dane_User.first.imie,
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  style: GoogleFonts.lato(
      textStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20.0,
          height: 1.2,
          color: Colors.white,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
)
```

Please let me know if you have any question. Hope this helps you!

Comment: Could you help me how to set the setter to the User class?

Comment: You can refer the following article for much better understanding of getter and setter in Dart class https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/getter-and-setter-methods-in-dart/